# Issue with Executing Commands in C Shell Program

Tags: c, execve

I'm currently working on a C shell program that takes user commands, searches for the command executable in the system's `PATH`, and then executes the command using `execve`. While the program seems to work correctly for the first execution, I'm encountering an issue when trying to execute another command in the same session.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

extern char **environ;

char *getcommand(char *command)
{
    char *path = getenv("PATH");
    char *token;
    char *execution;
    struct stat st;
    
    token = strtok(path, ":");
    
    while (token)
    {
        execution = malloc(strlen(token) + strlen(command) + 2);
        if (!execution)
        {
            // Handle memory allocation failure
            perror("malloc");
            return (1);
        }
        strcpy(execution, token);
        strcat(execution, "/");
        strcat(execution, command);
        if (stat(execution, &st) == 0)
        {
            return (execution);
        }
        free(execution);
        token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }
    return (NULL);
}

int main() {
    char *prompt = "$ ";
    ssize_t toread;
    char *command;
    size_t n = 0;
    const char *delim = " ";
    char *token, *atoken;
    int count = 0;
    char **argv;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    char *execution;
    int i = 0;
    
    while (1)
    {
        write(1, prompt, strlen(prompt));
        
        command = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        if (command == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        toread = getline(&command, &n, stdin);

        // Remove the newline character if present
        if (toread == -1)
        {
            printf("\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        if (toread > 0 && command[toread - 1] == '\n') {
            command[toread - 1] = '\0';
            toread--;
        }
        
        /* get the first token */
        token = strtok(command, delim);
   
       /* count tokens */
        argv = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
        while (token != NULL) {
            argv[count] = strdup(token);
            printf("2)- Token: %s\n", token);
            printf("-----------------------------\n");
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            count++;
        }
        argv[count] = NULL;
        printf("3)- Argv 0: %s\n", argv[0]);
        printf("-----------------------------\n");
        
        execution = getcommand(argv[0]);
        printf("execution: %s\n", execution);
        pid = fork();
        
        if (pid == -1)
        {
            perror("Fork Failed");
            return (1);
        }
        
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            if (execve(execution, argv, environ) == -1)
            {
                perror("Error in execution");
                free(execution);
                return (1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wait(&status);
            count = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            free(argv[i]);
        }
        free(execution);
        free(command);
        free(argv);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

I've been trying to debug this issue by examining the output and code, but I'm unable to pinpoint the root cause. The path search in the `getcommand` function seems to be working correctly, but something is going wrong when trying to execute the command. When I first type a command, for example `ls`, `execve`works just fine, but when I try for the second time in the same session, it gives this: `Error in execution: Bad address` and it seems like the problem is in execution.

Comment: You failed to re-initialise `int count = 0;` for the next command, possibly other variables too. Define your variables at the scope they will be used, for this where you say `/* count tokens */`.

Comment: Learn more about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html). Study for inspiration the source code of existing open source shells, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)

Comment: Aside: `command = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);` - note that this is `malloc(0)` on first pass, which invokes *implementation-defined* behaviour. [glibc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) returns a unique non-NULL pointer, but returning NULL is valid as well (per ISO C and per [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html)). More simply: (re-)initialize `command` as NULL, which will cause `getline` to allocate an appropriately sized buffer (can also reuse this buffer, and `n`, on subsequent iterations instead of allocating/freeing every time).

Comment: `argv[count] = NULL;` is UB if `token != NULL`: `argv` never grows to fit more than a single value, and UB if `token == NULL`: `getcommand(argv[0])` results in `strlen(NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

One likely issue is, that `strtok` modifies the underlying string (the path argument in your case). What's more, `getenv` gives you a pointer to the same underlying buffer each time it is called. The first call of `getcommand` succeeds (and returns some value), but by side-effect via `strtok`, "poisons" the environment for all subsequent invocations.

Either use a different (non-destructive) method to split the path, or make a copy of what `getenv` returns (and free it properly afterwards), use `getenv_s` if available, etc.